# ¿Se puede clonar un repositorio que no este dentro de GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Tengo un proyecto en un servidor del trabajo, me gustaría clonar ese repositorio en mi pc para trabajar con el y después mandar los cambio al servidor.
Es eso posible?

Comment: Siempre y cuando el repositorio esté expuesto a través de algún mecanismo de transporte soportado por git, por supuesto. Git no está atado a github o gitlab. Cualquiera puede tener sus repositorios "in house" sin mucha parafernalia.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el repositorio remoto con:

`git remote set-url origin git@yourrepo.com:user/repository`

y luego subir los cambios al nuevo repositorio